# is there a way to connect pin to shutdown

Tags: raspbian, power-management

There is the little trick of connecting pin 5-6 to load in recovery mode.

Is there an equivalent trick I missed to shutdown properly the pi using only a jumper ?

There is also the p6 connector, is it a hard-reset, or a soft one ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13203/creating-halt-wake-button/13214#13214

Comment: p6 is a hard reset of the broadcom chip.