# Prevent raspberry pi auto start?

Tags: boot, shutdown

Is it possible to prevent raspberry pi 3 from booting up automatically when i connect power?

Use case: i'm using *shutdown -h* for shutdown/halt, and then a push button in pins 5 & 6 to start again. I wan't that the first time i connect the pi to power, it stays "halted".

Idea: programmatically shutting it down when booting the first time?

Comment: Depends how much trouble (i.e. extra hardware) you want to go to.

Comment: Let's say without additional hardware (i could use a Pi Supply Switch but i is pretty overpriced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; it is not possible without some additional hardware.

---

Additional Information:-

When the Pi is shutdown, it enters a HALT state. However there is still code running, which is why the Pin5 can reboot. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19754/8697 for some explanation.

If the Pi has never been booted Pin5 will do nothing.

A better solution for the B+ (and later boards) is to use the `Run` header.

Still without some circuitry to hold the Pi in a HALT, it will boot on powerup.