# wake-from-halt on Raspberry Pi A+

Tags: pi-a+

I'm trying to use wake-from-halt on my Raspberry Pi A+, but it does not work. According to [elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode#cite_note-1](https://elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode#cite_note-1) When using bootcode.bin dated 12/04/2012 or later, the same two pins (5 & 6) can be momentarily shorted to wake the Raspberry Pi from the halted state. But this does not work :(

I also tried updating the bootloader. 
Is this feature implemented for the A+?

uname -a: Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34+ #1110 Mon Apr 16 14:51:42 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux

The script to halt the raspberry pi is working without any problems

Comment: Wake from halt? You mean booting from Etherrnet?

Comment: According to https://elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode#cite_note-1

When using bootcode.bin dated 12/04/2012 or later, the same two pins (5 & 6) can be momentarily shorted to wake the Raspberry Pi from the halted state.

But this does not work :(

Comment: Maybe the A+ has RUN pins (or holes...) marked on the board you could use instead?  Those should not require any firmware revision.

Comment: Aha, did you try [this](http://raspi.tv/2012/making-a-reset-switch-for-your-rev-2-raspberry-pi)?

Comment: The p6 works and will be my backup solution, as it only resets the board. With the wake-from-halt I could halt the board and later start it to safe power. I will probably end up with a timer in my application that brings the pi into halt after some time, which lets me use p6 to wake it again

Comment: P6 -> that's what I was thinking about with the "RUN pins".

Answer (score 1):

I an not sure you can actually "halt" the Pi with current Raspbian (although you may be able to write assembler to do so); all the normal shutdown commands run the same code.

The pin 5/6 does work (subject to a few caveats) - although I haven't tried on an A+ it works on all the B models.

If you want safe shutdown, Raspbian now includes code to do this `dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown` you don't need ANY code. See [Raspberry Pi 3 model B "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77905/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-dtoverlay-gpio-shutdown/77918#77918)

Comment: I explore the halt vs power off call stack through the kernel in [an answer of mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88471/71180). It appears a shutdown through the `reboot` syscall with `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF` or  `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT` , which is the case for `shutdown -h` triggers the system to prime for reset, this is the intended use case of the run pin IIRC