# Run script when Pi connects to any network

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am trying to make my RPI 4 execute a script, when it connects to a network (be it cable or wifi) i.e when it goes from not connected to connected.

I am running Raspbian (Buster) as OS and on Ubuntu 18.04 I can simply put the script in `NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` but since NetworkManager is not installed on my RPI (and I want to keep as clean an installation as possible) I tried to place it in `/etc/network/if-up.d` based on different answers years ago - it seems like `if-*` not used any more or..?

Any idea?

**Test-script:**

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "WORKING">out.txt
```

Comment: Your test script should probably use an absolute path for `out.txt`, otherwise it is likely to end up not where you thought it would.

Answer (score 4):

Dhcpdcd, which is used for DHCP client negotiation by default in Raspbian/RpiOS, has a "hooks" directory in `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks`.  Beware not to confuse `dhcpcd` with `dhclient`, which can serve much the same purpose and also entertains hooks (but is not used by default), or `dhcpd` (one less letter), which acts as a DHCP *server* (the `cd` in `dhcpcd` is for "*client* daemon").

`man dhcpcd-run-hooks` documents this very succinctly. When the script is run by `dhcpd`, the environment will contain a bunch of variables with information.  There is a list of a dozen or so reasons that this will happen; the specific one will be in `$reason`.

Try placing this there:<sup>1</sup>

```
reportLog=/some/absolute/path/dhcpcd-report.log

msg() {
    echo $@ >> $reportLog
}

date >> $reportLog
msg Invoked for $reason

# 'printenv' dumps all the environment variables
printenv >> $reportLog   

echo >> $reportLog
```

An example of the output:

```
Mon Jan 25 17:12:03 EST 2021
Invoked for BOUND
new_subnet_cidr=24
new_ip_address=192.168.0.21
new_network_number=192.168.0.0
pid=427
new_dhcp_message_type=5
if_down=false
ifmtu=1500
new_routers=192.168.0.1
new_subnet_mask=255.255.255.0
interface=wlan0
new_domain_name=hitronhub.home
reason=BOUND
ifcarrier=up
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ifssid=ISS2
protocol=dhcp
interface_order=lo eth0 wlan0
new_host_name=raspberrypi
if_up=true
new_dhcp_server_identifier=192.168.0.1
new_domain_name_servers=64.71.255.204 64.71.255.198
new_broadcast_address=192.168.0.255
WPAconfig=/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ifflags=69699
PWD=/
ifmetric=303
ifwireless=1
new_dhcp_lease_time=604800
```

A couple of the variables are inherited from the system (`$PATH`, `$PWD`), the rest are all from `dhcpcd` (many/most of them are described in the hooks man page).  Of particular relevance to you is of course `if_up=true`.  You'll have to experiment a bit to decide when you should do what it is you want to do.  For example, there's a distinction between an interface going up and an actual connection being established, and some specific combination of `$reason` and `$interface` may be the key you want to watch for; if you just do it every time a hook is run with `if_up=true` you will end up doing it three or four times in rapid succession, etc.

---

1. Dhcpcd executes this via `sh` (which is why there is no point in a shebang `#!/___`), meaning you can't use bashisms like `exec &>` to redirect all output (hence the cumbersome `msg()` function above) or capture the output of a command in a variable with `foo=$(bar)`.  However, you can get around that by making the hook script just:

   ```
    /bin/bash /path/to/some/bashscript.sh
   ```

You could do something similar to run a python script or execute anything; those environment variables are inherited.

Answer (score 2):

In the "good old days" there was **ifplugd** available with *Debian networking*, managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`. It monitors the network interfaces and calls a script if they change their state. But *Debian networking* isn't well supported on the Raspberry Pi OS, because it uses **dhcpcd** by default.

I have made *ifplugd* available again with *systemd-networkd*. How to use it you can look at [Make ifplugd available with systemd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96605/79866). You can also find a practical example at [How to make Raspian Buster shutdown when I unplug the ethernet cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/119349/79866).

Comment: You can add scripts to `dhcpcd` that trigger when an interface goes up, gets connected, etc., but it is perhaps slightly more labour intensive than `/etc/interface` stuff -- see `man dhcpcd-run-hooks`.   The script's environment will include things like `$interface` and `$if_up`, as described in that man page.  Unfortunately I don't have time to write an example right now...

Comment: I have tried adding `echo "test">./out.txt"` and placed it in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d` but nothing happens when I disconnect/connect again. The script can be run manually

Comment: @goldilocks I know about hook scripts with `dhcpcd` but I like to support **systemd** ;-)

Comment: @CutePoison You are mixing up things. With `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d` you try to configure the **isc-dhcp-client**. But that isn't used on RaspiOS. Used is `dhcpcd` (note the additional **c**) that must be configured in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: Does `ifplugd` work with wifi interfaces?

Comment: @goldilocks Yes. It isn't clearly stated in [man ifplugd](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ifplugd/ifplugd.8.en.html) but you will find it with option "-m | --api-mode= *MODE*" there.

Answer (score 1):

The

> dhcpcd-run-hooks

method worked for me.

I needed to activate a broadband usb-key connection before dhcpcd start to search for an IP on my wan interface

As stated from `man dhcpcd-run-hooks` i wrote my script in `/etc/dhcpcd.enter-hook` that is executed before system provided hooks in `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks`
If you need to execute your script as the  last one put it in `/etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook` instead.